# Is Debian 12 compatible with Python 3.5.4? (Segmentation fault error)

Tags: debian, python-3.5, pyenv, debian-bookworm

I've Debian 12 (PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)") installed on WSL2. And I'm trying to install Python3.5.4, but everytime I try that I get a segmentation fault error.

I've tried building from source as well as installation using pyenv.

Here the output of the installation using pyenv:

```
$ pyenv install 3.5.4
Downloading Python-3.5.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.4/Python-3.5.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.4...

BUILD FAILED (Debian GNU/Linux 12 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20240307153223.5850
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20240307153223.5850.log

Last 10 log lines:
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
        case upgrade in \
                upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
                install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
        esac; \
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20240307153223.5850/Python-3.5.4 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
                $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Segmentation fault
make: *** [Makefile:1048: install] Error 139
```

Python3.11 was pre-installed and it works fine.
Using pyenv I've installed (just for testing purposes) 3.7.1 as well as 3.5.10 and both were ok.

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.5.10
* 3.7.1 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

I've already installed (I hope all) dependencies using:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev tk-dev liblzma-dev lzma
```

Has anyone managed to install Python3.5.4 on Debian 12? How can I correct the segmentation fault error?